# How to delete duplicate files with the same size and date?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, postfix

For a reason I do not know, Postfix decided to duplicate all the emails I received in a specific folder after my return of vacation. Instead of having ~1000 emails in that folder, I now have 401120! That's way too much for Thunderbird, so the mail client refuse to download any of them.

When I ssh into the mail server, I can see the following:

```
-rw-------   68 user user     1415 Aug  3 17:45 502716210.M218413P5883.mail.domain.com,S=1415,W=1445:2,
-rw-------   68 user user     1415 Aug  3 17:45 502716327.M661584P5946.mail.domain.com,S=1415,W=1445:2,
-rw-------   68 user user     1415 Aug  3 17:45 502716331.M210364P5948.mail.domain.com,S=1415,W=1445:2,
-rw-------   68 user user     1415 Aug  3 17:45 502716412.M161709P6009.mail.domain.com,S=1415,W=1445:2,
-rw-------   42 user user     2393 Aug  3 17:44 502714577.M151447P4492.mail.domain.com,S=2393,W=2447:2,
-rw-------   42 user user     2393 Aug  3 17:44 502715910.M338737P5564.mail.domain.com,S=2393,W=2447:2,
-rw-------   42 user user     2393 Aug  3 17:44 502715914.M370949P5566.mail.domain.com,S=2393,W=2447:2,
-rw-------   42 user user     2393 Aug  3 17:44 502715964.M213570P5615.mail.domain.com,S=2393,W=2447:2,
```

I can see that Postfix gave all files their own name, but when I look with nano, I can see that all files with the same size and date are identical.

How can I delete all the duplicate files, to get only one file for each size-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this to a file (say: kill_dupes) and add run rights (chmod a+x kill_dupes) and run it

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -gGlt | sort -k4,6 -k3,3n > filelist.txt

awk '
BEGIN   {
        printf("#!/bin/bash\n\n");
        filename0 = $7;
        filesize0 = $3;
        filedate0 = $4$5$6;
    }

NF>2    {
        filename1 = $7;
        filesize1 = $3;
        filedate1 = $4$5$6;
        if(filesize1==filesize0 && filedate1==filedate0) {
            printf("rm %s\n", filename1);
        } else {
            filename0 = filename1;
            filesize0 = filesize1;
            filedate0 = filedate1;
        }       
    }
' filelist.txt > rmdupes.sh
```

then verify the content of **rmdupes.sh** file

```
head rmdupes.sh
```

please check it before actually running it.

(is **502715964.M213570P5615.mail.domain.com,S=2393,W=2447:2** an actual filename?)

Comment: It worked! Well, mostly. It reduced from 401120 to 46703. But when they are duplicates of different size on the same time, no duplicates are deleted:

-rw-------   42     1394 Aug  3 18:13 1502716331.M210367P5948.mail.domain.com,S=1394,W=1424:2,
-rw-------   41     2339 Aug  3 18:13 1502716331.M210368P5948.mail.domain.com,S=2339,W=2390:2,
-rw-------   42     1394 Aug  3 18:13 1502716412.M161712P6009.mail.domain.com,S=1394,W=1424:2,
-rw-------   41     2339 Aug  3 18:13 1502716412.M161713P6009.mail.domain.com,S=2339,W=2390:2,

Comment: sort added after ls. Please try it this way, it should work now :-)